# Java Regex: Matcher.find problems

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble distinguishing two templates when I aplly match.find().

```
String template1 = "GET /boards/(.+?)";
String template2 = "GET /boards/(.+?)/lists";
```

When given the following input : "GET /boards/boardName/lists" , it matches with the first template instead of the second. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the first one, `+?` will still match (**non-greedily**) the character after the last forward slash because `.` matches any single character except newline. Therefore, it matches on this expression first. If you don't want the first expression to match, change it to `GET /boards/([^/]+)$`

Comment: Are you sure that input won't actually match both?

Comment: In the first case, group 1 contains `boardName/lists`. In the second case group 1 contains `boardName`. Both patterns will match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of that `(.+?)` will match every combinations of characters with length 1 or more which will make your regex engine match the following part :

```
boardName/lists
```

Also note that if you first try the following regex :

```
GET /boards/(.+?)/lists
```

It will match the string too but the difference is that in this regex the group 1 will be contain `boardName`, but in the first one the group 1 will be `b` (because of `?` which makes `.+` a none greedy pattern ).

If you want that the first regex not match your string you can use a [*negative look ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match the strings that are not followed by word `list` :

```
GET /boards/([^/]+)(?!lists)
```

Comment: @hwnd Yep, that will match the strings that just have one word after `GET /boards/`.

Comment: Can you please check this: https://ideone.com/u75KTR I am getting different output then what you have mentioned.

Comment: @YoungHobbit yep, sorry I missed that point, the first regex group 1 will be the character `b` because of none greedy matching